# How to make np.loadtxt return multidimensional arrays even the file has only one dimensional?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to get the last four column data of a `ndarray`, most of time code `arr[:, -4:]` is ok, but if the array just has one dimension, this will throw `IndexError: too many indices`.

My data is get with `arr = np.loadtxt('test.txt')`, so if `test.txt` has more than one line, like

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 10 20 30 40
```

everything is ok, but if `test.txt` has just one line, like

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

this will return `array([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])`, then `arr[:, -4:]` will throw exception, because it should be `arr[-4:]`, so how to make `loadtxt` return `array([[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])`?

Comment: @gg349 there are no better ways? If better way to get the last column data is also ok

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found it [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

You can ask it to have at least 2 dimensions with:

```
arr = np.loadtxt('test.txt', ndmin=2)
```

Comment: I was looking for this for some time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Ellipsis` (`...`) instead of an empty `slice` (`:`) for your first index:

```
>>> a = np.arange(30).reshape(3, 10)
>>> a[:, -4:]
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [26, 27, 28, 29]])
>>> a[..., -4:]  # works the same for the 2D case
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [26, 27, 28, 29]])

>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a[..., -4:]  # works also in the 1D case
array([6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a[:, -4:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

**EDIT** If you want the return to be 2D also for the single row case, then this should do the trick:

```
>>> np.atleast_2d(a[..., -4:])
array([[6, 7, 8, 9]])
```